# do not runder component on login

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am new with react
I follow a course with typescript, but after I create components
in the course he display it in all routers
I need to not display in login page only
is there any way to achieve that
here part from my code in App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Login} from "./components/Login";
import {Nav} from "./components/Nav";
import {Home} from "./components/Home";
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
return <BrowserRouter>
<Nav/>
<Routes>
 <Route path="/login" element = {<Login/>} />
<Route path="/" element = {<Home/>} />
</Routes>

</BrowserRouter>;
}
```

the Nav component is the component I need to not show in Login component
thanks in advance

Comment: First, Welcome you to StackOverflow. Your asking is not clear. If Login is not imported in the App function it will not be displayed in the app UI. You just delete the Route path that is defined in your App function.

Comment: I need to display the Nav comp in other route like Home and other will be added soon but I want not runder it in Login rout

Comment: In other word I need navbar in all pages except login

Comment: thank you for your answer , i hope I am asking clearly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating a new folder as a page named Home, About,... ... . Import components in these new components. Don't import Navbar where it is not necessary. Sample code:

```
function Home() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Banner></Banner>
        <Info></Info>
      </div>
```

```
function Login() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Banner1></Banner1>
        <Info1></Info1>
      </div>
```

Finally, import Home and Login in the app.js function.

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
     </Routes>
```

Hope it would work.